# How to downgrade Chrome from dev to beta channel without losing my profile?

Tags: google-chrome, uninstall, downgrade

**Would it be possible to downgrade from the dev channel (6.0.477.0) to version 5 without losing my profile(s)?**

I was thinking either by downgrading without having to uninstall my current version, or by backing up the profile folders. Would this cause any issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found that you only need to copy that folder, remove the newer version, and install the older.

#### User profile location in Chrome (stable, beta, dev)

XP: `C:\Documents and Settings\<Username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data`

Vista/Win7: `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`

#### User profile location in Chrome (canary)

XP: `C:\Documents and Settings\<Username>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome SxS\User Data`

Vista/Win7: `C:\Users\<Username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\User Data`

Unfortunately, it may cause some issues, because Chrome shows the following alert on every start:

> Your profile can not be used because it is from a newer version of
>    Google Chrome. 
>   Some features may be unavailable. Please specify a different profile
>   directory or use a newer version of Chrome.